# Perforce Plugin and Visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, perforce

I am using Perforce as source control. I have install latest plugin for VS 2010 from perforce site. However, visual studio always set the selected scc plugin to None before closing. When I reopen the VS 2010 I need to again select the correct Plugin from None to Perforce to continue the work.

Is there any solution?

Comment: please make sure your project file is check out, otherwise the settings where you set the source control are being overwritten. regards.